# ColdFusion calling a bootstrap modal from another file

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

I'm creating all the modals if my project in a different file (modals.cfm). How can I call a modal from another file?

modals.cfm (A bootstrap modal example)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="requestError" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">X</button>
            <h4 id="myModalLabel1" class="modal-title"><strong>Error!</strong></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                <h2 id="error"></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick="myFunc();">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, I would like to call it from another cfm file. For instance, index.cfm:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="callModal();"> Test </button>

<script>
    function callModal(){
        $("#error").html("My custom error message");

        $("#requestError").modal(); // How can I call it from another file?
    }
</script>
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to AJAX in the modal?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean? I use JQuery to open the modal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the more "fundamental" things that helped me understand ColdFusion is thinking of it this way: ColdFusion's purpose is to generate HTML.

Now, based on your description, you say you want to use the HTML that you generated in `modals.cfm`.  That's good, but how is it to be inserted on the page you are on right now (for example: `index.cfm`)?

A simple, straightforward way would be to do a CFINCLUDE on `index.cfm` to modals.cfm:

```
<!-- index.cfm code here--->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="callModal();"> Test </button>

<cfinclude template="modals.cfm">
<script>
    function callModal(){
        $("#error").html("My custom error message");

        $("#requestError").modal(); // How can I call it from another file?
    }
</script>
```

If you want to load the page through AJAX (as James mentioned above), it would be a bit more work, but definitely doable.  We'll just need more code.

Comment: Thank you. Idk why somebody gave you a negative point. It is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Negative comments happen. I know I have deserved most of the ones I have gotten. But if no feedback is given, there is no clear way to improve.